# angular.js merging controllers into 1

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a question about merging a few controllers into 1. I'm showing some links based on user status(logged in or not)

I used to have Login(http post login),Register,Logout(http post logout),User(http update some settings) controllers. I merged them into 1. Is that a good decision?

```
app.controller('UserCtrl', function($scope,..) {
  $scope.logged = state;
  this.login = function() {
    ..
    $scope.logged = 1;
  };
  this.logout = function() {
    ..
    $scope.logged = 0;
  };
  this.update = function() {
    ..
  };this.register..
});
```

This controller would be also used in other templates or for examples 2x on same template. Isn't it wrong?

```
<div ng-controller="UserCtrl as userCtrl">
    <li ng-show="logged">..</li>
</div>
<!-- some code -->
<div ng-controller="UserCtrl as userCtrl">
   <button ng-click="userCtrl.logout()">Logout</button>
</div>...etc.
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I would lean more in the direction of moving the logic that the controllers shared into a factory, then pulling the factory into any controllers that need access to that logic. but, what you're doing isn't "wrong", if it works, right? it just may not be the "best" way to accomplish it (which in and of itself is pretty subjective anyway).

Comment: So isn't it wrong if each controller would consists just with one function doing $http request?

Comment: I would consider it a bad practice to send an  http request in a controller. but, it isn't "wrong".

Comment: so you suggest me to move everything into factory? then controllers would have just 1 line where will be service calling

Comment: Depends on needs. If all you need in Controller A is whether or not the user is logged in, you would simply need to store that status on the controller's scope. `$scope.loggedIn = authService.isLoggedIn;` Of course, you would need some kind of event too for when the user logs in or out so that the controller will know when that value changes.

Comment: I just need controller/s which would react on some form submits(login, logout, update) + loggedIn state. That's the original question:if I should add it into 1 controller or into multiple. But probably 1 would be enough if all $http functions will be in a factory